# Derivar polinomios PYTHON SYMPY

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Después de descubrir que sympy sí funciona en mi pc jajaja, se da a lugar a un nuevo problema, necesito derivar un polinomio para después integrarlo (Necesito sacar longitud de arco de una función)
**Lo que ya tengo: 
Almaceno el polinomio desde el teclado en un arreglo 
Se deriva por diff (Instrucción de sympy) 
**Mi duda: 
Usando el metodo de Simpson 1/3, lo tengo que integrar, sin embargo me tira el error

```py
'int' object has no attribute 'diff'
```

¿Cómo puedo tratar de integrar esta derivada?
Muchas gracias a todos por ayudarme
Adjunto las operaciones del metodo de Simpson

```py
def simpson13(g,a,b):
    m=(a+b) / 2
    integral= (b - a) / 6 *(g(a) + 4 * g(m) + g(b))
    return integral 


n = 100
dx=(b - a) / n
suma = 0
for i in range(n):  
    b = a + dx
    area= simpson13(g, a, b)
    suma = suma + area 
    a = b

print(suma)
def simpson13(g,a,b):
    m=(a+b) / 2
    integral= (b - a) / 6 *(g(a) + 4 * g(m) + g(b))
    return integral 


n = 100
dx=(b - a) / n
suma = 0
for i in range(n):  
    b = a + dx
    area= simpson13(g, a, b)
    suma = suma + area 
    a = b

print(suma)
```

Comment: Hola Darío,  antes de intentar reinventar la rueda XD ¿que versión de Python tienes? ¿Por que dices que no funciona con tu verión de Python? ¿Algún error al instalar? ¿Sistema operativo?

Comment: @FJSevilla Jajaja, tengo la versión 3.7 de python, perdón por no ponerla, intenté instalarlo y todo bien, de hecho en el prompt de anaconda, me aparece como instalado, pero al quererlo usar me aparece que no existe, después de volver a intentar de todo, encontré en un blog de anaconda, que  no funciona en las versiones nuevas de este mismo.

Comment: Dos cositas: la pregunta ahora es totalmente diferente que el original. Eso no es la función de editar preguntas, por que ahora la respuesta original ya no encaja para nada. Tendria que ser un post nuevo. Otra cosa: hace falta importar librería, dar valores iniciales a todo (`a`, `b`, `g`) para obtener un ejemplo completo y quitar el copy-paste doble. Si hay un error, al menos hay que explicar en que linea y con que variables pasa.

Comment: No olvides votar para respuestas útiles. Y [aceptar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas/428#428) una respuesta si esta respuesta resuelve la pregunta.

Comment: @DaríoValerio, si te ha sido de utilidad la respuesta proprocionada, puedes marcarla como válida. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo, la librería simbólica de Python se llama ['sympy'](https://www.sympy.org/es/index.html). La librería 'simpy' tiene que ver con simulaciones.

Una diferencia entre Python y muchos programas de matemáticas simbólicas, es que en Python el simbolo `^` solo funciona como ["Disyunción exclusiva"](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#two-final-notes-and) (XOR). Para potencias hay que emplear `**`.

La función [`Derivative`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html) sirve para derivar. Sin nada más, solo represente el derivado sin evaluar. Para evaluarlo, hay que añadir la función `.doit()`.

Alternativamente, la función [`diff`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html#derivatives) calcula el derivado sin necesidad de `.doit()`.

Un ejemplo:

```py
from sympy import Symbol, Derivative, diff, sin, sympify

x = Symbol('x')
print(Derivative(x**2).doit()) # 2*x
print(diff(sin(x**2)) # 2*x*cos(x**2)
print(diff(1/sin(x**2))) # -2*x*cos(x**2)/sin(x**2)**2
```

No se puede emplear `diff` con una expresión que no sea de tipo `sympy`. Pero si con el resultado de otro `diff`. Y tambien con constantes convertido en tipo `sympy`:

```py
print(diff(7*x)) # 7
print(diff(diff(7*x))) # 0
print(diff(sympify(23))) # 0
```

Para derivar un polinomio:

```py
def derivar_polinomio(coef, x):
    p = sum([c * x**i  for i, c in enumerate(coef[::-1])])
    return diff(p)

print(derivar_polinomio([7, 3, 5], x)) # 14*x + 3
```

Para la pregunta nueva, supongo que la idea seria que `g` es derivado de una función `x**2` y `a` y `b` son 2 constantes. Para evaluar `g` con `x` substituido por `a`, en sympy se calcula como `g.subs(x, a)`. Sympy lo mire como expresiones más que como funciones.

```py
from sympy import diff, Symbol

def simpson13(g, a, b):
    m = (a + b) / 2
    integral = (b - a) / 6 * (g.subs(x, a) + 4 * g.subs(x, m) + g.subs(x, b))
    return integral

x = Symbol('x')
g = diff(x ** 2)
a = 2
b = 3

n = 100
dx = (b - a) / n
suma = 0
for i in range(n):
    b = a + dx
    area = simpson13(g, a, b)
    suma += area
    a = b

print(suma)
```

Comment: muchas gracias por contestar, una pregunta más, se puede derivar con derivate un polinomio almacenado con la instrucción 'np.poly1d'?

Comment: El asunto es que el usuario tiene que insertar un polinomio, este se almacena en un arrelo y de ahí no sé como puedo derivarlo e integrarlo, ya intenté pasarlo a función, y ahora estoy intentando con 'np.poly1d'

Comment: Gracias nuevamente por contestar, @JohanC, disculpa, habrá alguna manera de usar esa derivada de sympy, con operaciones aritmeticas? Es decir, que me dé el resultado de una cierta derivada y esta pasarla a función para evaluarla y poder integrar? Especificamente hablando de la regla o metodo de simpson Gracias

Comment: Ya que al querer integrar con operaciones aritmeticas la derivada que me tira diff, me lanza este error: 'int' object has no attribute 'diff'

Comment: gracias nuevamente por seguir contestando

Comment: gracias por tu tiempo, ya edité el post y creo que puse todo, en serio gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada y/o votarla